# Unable to connect to Cloud Sql (postgres) from firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I am using nodejs firebase functions. I use `sequlize` to connect to the `postgres` db.

I tried following the doc https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql to connect to the db from firebase functions, but I am not able to connect. I get this error.

```
Failed to prune sessions: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
```

This is the configuration that I use.

```
{ username: 'postgres',
    password: '*********',
    database: 'testdb',
    host: '/cloudsql/my-project:us-central1:db-instance',
    port: 5432,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: { ssl: false }}
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: I don't know anything about sequlize, but I'll ask if you're you sure that host string is correct?  Something is trying to connect to the local Cloud Functions instance, which is obviously not right.

Comment: @DougStevensonn thanks for the hint. I got it fixed. Btw the  fire base carol was awesome : )

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I was also using `pg session` and it was using a connection string. I guess pg was not able to differentiate the host from the connection string.

After replacing the connection string with a pg pool object, I was able to connect.